# ASP.NET C# file locked on folder by process not allowing new OleDbConnection connections to different files

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledbconnection

I am trying to solve an issue that i have been smashing my head against the wall about. What i am trying to accomplish is to read the table names (sheet names) from an excel file that is stored in a folder on the web server. I am going to use these sheet names to determine what sheet i will read values from. The problem that i am having is that users randomly come across the issue where a file gets locked by the asp.net process and then no other users in different sessions and with different files can access their files on the folder. Once the file is locked i am unable to delete the file from the data folder because it is being used by another process.

The only thing that will free up the folder is to do an app pool refresh. I am running my app pool in X64 to accomondate for the XLSX and XLS files. I have had the server team run the procmon tool to see what processes have the folder locked up and got no useful information.

I have my connection to my file location wrapped in using statements to make sure proper disposal is being done. When a file gets locked or doesn't exit the process of the using statement it does not allow for users to create a new connection to another completely unique and different file in the same location. Users are able to write a file to the folder location and delete a file but not able to execute the conn.Open in the below code. Users are not able to navigate to the folder location and delete the file that is locked by the process either. As i said earlier this happens randomly and is hard to recreate. I have looked into whether the folder had indexing or backup jobs running but they do not.

I have tried to put a lock object around the processing so that no other process can access the file while i am pulling values from the file. The tricky part is that after an app pool refresh i cannot get the file lock to occur for a while....its like it runs out of connection objects and or the app pool bogs down to where 2 processes try and access the file simultaneously or something. Our app pool refreshes every 24 hours so it will automatically release the object and we are able to to delete the file and also able to pull data from other excel sheet on the folder. But we can't run an app pool refresh randomly during the day if we see this locked process issue.

```
public const string ExcelConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;ReadOnly=True;\"";

    DataTable dt = ExecuteDataTable(connectionString, String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}] ", sheetName.Trim())); 
    string connectionString = DataServices.ExcelConnection;
            string fileConnection = string.Format(connectionString, mappedPath.Trim());

            Object lockObject = new Object();
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                // Setup the connection to the file
                using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(fileConnection))
                {
                    if (File.Exists(mappedPath))
                    {
                        try
                        {                                                        
                            conn.Open();                            
                            this.sheetNamesFromFile = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

                            if (this.sheetNamesFromFile.Rows.Count > 0)
                            {                                
                                this.sheetName = RetrieveSheetName(this.sheetNamesFromFile, fileName);
                                ViewState.Add("SheetName", this.sheetName.ToString().Trim());                               

                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.sheetName))
                                {   
                                    this.massUploadExcelData = DataServices.GetExcelData(conn.ConnectionString, this.sheetName, fileName);    // getexcledata has the following code to grab all data from the sheet name - DataTable dt = ExecuteDataTable(connectionString, String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}] ", sheetName.Trim())); 


                                    if (this.massUploadExcelData.Rows.Count < 1)
                                    {
                                        this.ShowMessageOnSubmit(this.Labels.GetLabel("norecordsintable"), false);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    this.ShowMessageOnSubmit(this.Labels.GetLabel("uploadnosheet"), false);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException dataExp)
                        {
                            EventLogging.LogError("An error has occurred when saving a mass upload file, the file the user is using could have corrupt data : Mapped path = " + mappedPath + " File Path and Name = " + fileName, dataExp);
                            this.error = "An error has occured when trying to load a mass upload file, user might have corrupt data. exception = " + dataExp;
                            return string.Empty;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        EventLogging.LogError("The file does not exist that is trying to be accessed in the application, mapped path - " + mappedPath);
                    }
                }

                // Delete the file in data folder, since we already have the datatable of the data and sheet name            
                if (File.Exists(mappedPath))
                {
                    DeleteFile(mappedPath);
                }
            }
```

Any thoughts and direction would be appreciatted.

Comment: do you know how to Dispose of ComObjects when using `Interop` this sounds like you have many instances open of `Excel.exe` right click on TaskManager and see how many are locked in memory..

Comment: The code has been chopped off half way through, can you post the rest of it?

Comment: DJ KRAZE - i will add some logging to see if i can get the number of open processes and let you know the status while the server team gives me access to the server.

Comment: There are no excel.exe processes running when the file gets stuck. the only process that is running is the w3p.exe process of the current application. I am not sure why the process is locked on the excel file and why no other users can even connect to a different excel file with different processes.